# Preprocess node from a module: not getting same vars as template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'd like to preprocess and theme my nodes from a module instead of template.php.  Before, I'd have a giant switch statement in `theme_preprocess_node()`.  But this only ever applied to my primary tab - subtabs were being templated from the modules they were defined in.  So I like the idea of consolidating all my preprocess functions and templates into one organized module.

The structure I want is essentially like this (pulling out details for a summary):

```
function foomodule_menu()
{
    $items['foo/%node'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'page_foo_overview',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
        $items['foo/%node/overview'] = array(
            'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
        );
        $items['foo/%node/details'] = array(
            'page callback' => 'page_foo_details',
            'page arguments' => array(1),
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        );
}

function foomodule_theme()
{
    return array(
        'page_foo_overview' => array(
            'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
            'template' => 'templates/page-foo-overview'
        ),
        'page_foo_details' => array(
            'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
            'template' => 'templates/page-foo-details'
        ),
    );
}

function page_foo_overview($node)
{
    // Used to do this, and themed it from template.php
    // return node_view($node, FALSE, TRUE);

    // Instead, I'd like to theme all pages directly in this module:
    return theme('page_foo_overview', $node);
}

function template_preprocess_page_foo_overview(&$vars)
{
    // But $vars doesn't contain the same data as when I themed from template.php
    // Specifically the ['view'] element of CKK fields, and flags like $teaser
    // What do I need to do to get at the same data?
    dsm($vars);
}
```

All works great, but the $vars available in my preprocess are not what I'm used to in the template.php's `theme_preprocess_node()` function.  For one, it looks like CCK fields haven't been run through `content_format()` (no ['view'] element), and flags like `teaser` and `page` are missing.

What's being called before `theme_preprocess_node()` that I could invoke here?

Am I asking for trouble by doing this?  It makes so much more sense to me to have it organized like this and be in control of each step: menu > page callback > theme > preprocess > template, and to be able to organize this across multiple modules as I see fit.

Answer (score 1):

AK,

My suggestion is to execute the following code to check the available variables

```
<?php  
$arr = get_defined_vars();  
dsm($arr);  
?>
```

If that doesn't help you can check the weight of your module on the system table. Maybe changing it (to make your module run after other modules) can help you.